# Multiple connections, session state

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

My goal is to have:

- 1 persistent database connection and transaction which inserts/updated data, and can be committed or rolled back when all the work is done
- "at-will" opened unrelated connections which DO NOT share session state with the persistent connection - meaning they "see" old data. These connections only need to read, not write.

I tried opening a completely new connection but it sees the changes made by the persistent connection. Is this possible to achieve?

Note: I am using the same Oracle username/password for all the connections.

Note 2: Toad (software for Oracle DB) doesn't "see" the changes made by the persistent connection until they are committed. If they are rolled back, they don't appear in the database, when they are committed, they do. That part works fine, it's just that other connection opened from my application sees them before they are committed.

Here's the code for my connection which sees changes it shouldn't see:

```
using (OracleConnection readConnection = new 
       OracleConnection(Settings.OracleConnectionString))
{
    readConnection.Open();

    using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(lastOracleRowQuery, 
                                                     readConnection))
    {
        using (OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    compareValues.Add(reader.IsDBNull(i) ? 
                        null : 
                        reader.GetValue(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This happens while there is another OracleConnection open, and a transaction using that connection. However, shouldn't readConnection be completely unrelated?

The result of this read gives results that do not appear when using the same query in Toad at the same time.

**Solved**

Apparently, **Oracle commits the session on "CREATE TABLE" even if the create table fails, does nothing and throws an exception**. I did not expect this behavior so this is what confused me. When I put all the table-creating at the start, everything started working. No tables were actually being created during my testing so I didn't think that was the problem, but when I cleaned up the code and moved them to the start everything fixed itself.

I still don't understand what was going on with Toad though. I might have been mistaken or something. Or there are more bugs I am not aware of yet. :D

Comment: if using the default read committed, is it possible you're using the same connection/session for both? (pooling).

Comment: The connections are completely separate object, except for 2 things: both use the same username/password, and the function that creates the "read" connection is called withing the "using" block of the persistent connection and transaction.

Comment: I added the ALTER SESSION command you suggested to the read connection and it started working. Then, I commented it out, and it's still working. Now I'm confused.

Comment: Actually, the alter session isn't important, I figured it out.

Comment: Connection pooling is enable in ODP.NET by default.  You may want to consider wrapping your DML code that you want "hidden" in a pragma autonomous procedure in the db.

Comment: if you figured it out, care to share with everyone?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using System.Transaction.TransactionScope, then all the connections created within the scope will be treated as a single transaction and hence the data created by your persistent connection will be visible to the read connection.

You should create a new TransactionScope within the current scope with the scope option as TransactionScopeOption.Suppress, create the read connection within that scope and do your read operation in that new scope. Your code will look as below.

```
//Outer Transaction        
using (TransactionScope t = new TransactionScope())
{
        //Create persistence connection and command
        // Execute persistence commands
        //Inner scope to suppress the outer transaction
    using (TransactionScope t1 = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
    {
        //create read connection
        // Execute read operation
    }
    //continue with write operation
}
```

Comment: That would explain my problem but I'm not, I'm using OracleTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(), then command.Transaction = transaction;